# Workflow email for Approval process

Tags: workflow

I've created an "Approval - SharePoint 2010" workflow on a list that has content approval enabled. Each time a user adds, deletes, or edits a list item, it should send an email to the approver with a link to allow the user to not only approve/reject, but also reassign and request changes. But the email contains a link to a page showing the list item with "Approve/Reject" and "Workflows" buttons at the top; there's no button to choose reassign or request changes.

Here's the email:

```
Approval has started on (no title).
Participants are Jane Smith
Due by 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Each person will receive a task to approve (no title). The tasks will be assigned one at a time for participants shown above.

__________________________________________________
View the status of this workflow.
```

How do you assign an out of the box workflow to a list so it allows the user to approve/reject the document, reassign the task, or request changes to the document? I thought that the "Approval - SharePoint 2010" workflow already did that. I also tried the "Publishing Approval" and it yielded the same results.

What am I missing? Thanks.